# How to use intl-tel-input plugin utilsscript in angular 2+ Project?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

- Module : ng2-tel-input,
- Project : Angular 4,
- JS plugin : intl-tel-input

After installing **npm i ng2-tel-input**

I saw a comment inside node_modules\intl-tel-input\src\js\intlTelInput.js file saying

```
//specify the path to the libphonenumber script to enable validation/formatting
```

for `utilsScript: ""`

How can I use this utilsScript inside my angular project typescript file? Can someone please give a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can find how to add utilsScript on official page of that plugin
https://github.com/gauravsoni119/ng2-tel-input

You just need to add utilsScript in plugin options:

```
[ng2TelInputOptions]="{initialCountry: 'in', utilsScript: 'node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js'}"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this plugin - intl-input-phone.

```
npm i intl-input-phone
```

[See the NPM link for more information npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl-input-phone)

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/surajmathe/intl-input-phone)

[Demo Link 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/intl-input-phone-demo)

[Demo Link 2](https://intl-input-phone-demo.stackblitz.io/)